# Is it possible to check the output of previous step in the same script

Tags: bash, sh

The script runs two scripts depending on the output of the first script, i want to choose to run the script or not. For e.g

Mainscript.sh

`./script1.sh....`

is there a way to check output of script1.sh in mainscript.sh?
Because if output that there is connection between two system then i need to run the second script. Can i do it with python or i can do with bash only?

Comment: Grab the output of `script1` by using `out=$(./script1.sh)` and then examine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common arrangement is to write your scripts so that programmatic operation is convenient. In concrete terms, that means that your script should return a zero exit code on success, nonzero otherwise. Then what you ask for is a simple matter of

```
 script1 && script2
```

or in more complex cases

```
if script1; then
    echo "$0: countdown to takeoff" >&2
    script2
else
    echo "$0: trouble occurred" >&2
    script1 --reverse --undo --apologize
    script3 || make clean
    echo "$0: reverted everything" >&2
fi
```

Comment: are these options standard? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the last command exit code in `$?`. Also you can save its output.

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT=`./script1.sh`
echo $?
echo $OUTPUT
```